# How to refer to Visio object in MS Access Control

Tags: ms-access, vba, visio

I have a 'Microsoft Visio Document' (VisioViewer.Viewer.1) control (called visDiagram) on an MS Access form.
How can I refer to it in code?

e.g.

```
  Dim pagDiagram as Visio.Page
  Set pagDiagram = me!visDiagram.<WHAT GOES HERE????>
  Debug.print pagDiagram.Shapes.Count
```

UPDATE:
This web page http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff765109(v=office.14).aspx says use

```
Dim vsoDocument As Visio.Document
Set vsoDocument = DrawingControl1.Document
```

but

```
Dim vsoDocument As Visio.Document
Set vsoDocument = me!visDiagram.Document
```

gives 'Object does not support his property or method'

Comment: you again omit .Object property of visDiagram control

Comment: Even with the .Object, I still don't see how I get the page and it's shapes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
set vsoDocument  = me!visDiagram.Object
Debug.print vsoDocument.ShapeCount

for each P in vsoDocument.Pages  
     debug.print P.name
next p
```

Comment: Thanks, but that didn't work. Actually it did work but it's the page I'm after so I can access the shapes, not just a count of the shapes

Comment: please try and say which line faults

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. I've pasted your code in. It's the 'For' line which errors: Runtime error 438, Object does not support this property or method. Putting a Watch on vsoDocument I can see lots of properties, ie. AlertsEnabled, BackColor, BuildNumber but no collections of pages or anything like that

Comment: me!visDiagram.Object returns VisioViewer.Viewer.1 and I couldn't find anything useful in it, may be you can change its' type to something else?

Comment: I think you're right. I need the Visio Drawing Control, not the viewer. Not sure how I get that as only the viewer is listed in the ActiveX controls list in the MS Access form design toolbox

Comment: try to use OLE unbound control and put visio document there.

Comment: Yep, I needed to repair my Visio instllation to make the Microsoft Office Visio Drawing Control appear in the list of Access controls. The viewer control doesn't give you access the the pages etc.